# Transform a -> a -> Maybe a to take any combination of a's and Maybe a's

Tags: haskell

I have a function `f` of type `Integral => a -> a -> Maybe a`. This means that

```
f 1 2
```

is valid code, but natural compositions like

```
f (f 3 4) 5
f 6 (f 7 8)
f (f 9 10) (f 11 12)
```

are not valid.

There are ways to make it work. For example,

```
f 6 =<< f 7 8
```

is the nicest way I know for case 2. For case 3,

```
join $ f <$> f 9 10 <*> f 11 12
```

is the best I can think of, but the extra `join` sticks out like a sore thumb. I don't have a good idea for case 1. Besides that, what bothers me is that the syntax in what I came up with is not "consistent" - I'm accomplishing essentially the same thing, but the syntax is very dissimilar.

Is there a standard/idiomatic construction which allows me to convert `f` to work as `Maybe a -> a -> Maybe a`, `a -> Maybe a -> Maybe a`, and `Maybe a -> Maybe a -> Maybe a`, with nice and consistent syntax?

Comment: A single function that can accept both `a` and `Maybe a` cannot exist in Haskell, even overloaded. I would go with something of type `Maybe a -> Maybe a -> Maybe a` always, and insert `Just` as needed.

Comment: @n.m. You can using closed type family and probably funDep. You end up having a signature like `(Maybable b a, Maybable c a) => b -> c -> Maybe a`.

Comment: @mb14 You can make concrete types like Int Maybable, but I think not something like `Integral a => a`.

Comment: @mb14 "The closed type familes allows you to defines rules which overlap and use the first which matches" didn't know that, cool.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

### Original Solution

Let's create a utility function for the first case:

```
lift :: (a -> b -> Maybe c) -> Maybe a -> b -> Maybe c
lift _ Nothing  _ = Nothing
lift f (Just a) b = f a b
```

**Case 1:**

```
lift f (f 3 4) 5
```

**Case 2:**

```
f 6 =<< f 7 8
```

**Case 3:**

```
lift f (f 9 10) =<< f 11 12
```

Although it looks more consistent, yet in my humble opinion it still looks ugly. Perhaps somebody else could provide a better solution.

### Recommended Solution

**Edit:** After thinking about my solution I realized that it can be generalized:

```
(<&>) :: (Applicative m, Monad m) => m (a -> m b) -> m a -> m b
f <&> a = join $ f <*> a
infixl 4 <&>
```

**Case 1:**

```
f <$> f 3 4 <&> pure 5
```

**Case 2:**

```
f <$> pure 6 <&> f 7 8
```

**Case 3:**

```
f <$> f 9 10 <&> f 11 12
```

This works for functions of an arbitrary arity:

```
f <$> a <&> b             -- f :: a -> a -> Maybe a

f <$> a <*> b <&> c       -- f :: a -> a -> a -> Maybe a

f <$> a <*> b <*> c <&> d -- f :: a -> a -> a -> a -> Maybe a
```

And so on....

### Alternate Solution

**Edit:** I <strike>agree</strike> with @n.m. The best solution would be to change the type signature of your function to `Maybe a -> Maybe a -> Maybe a` and use `Just` wherever necessary.

**Case 1:**

```
f (f (Just 3) (Just 4)) (Just 5)
```

**Case 2:**

```
f (Just 6) (f (Just 7) (Just 8))
```

**Case 3:**

```
f (f (Just 9) (Just 10)) (f (Just 11) (Just 12))
```

The simplest solutions are always the best.

**Edit:** Actually, in retrospect my previous solution was much simpler.

Answer (score 2):

This is not standard or idiomatic but it's solves your problem using closed
typed families.
What you want is a super `return` which doesn't wrap a value if it's the value is already wrapped, so that `return' 4 = Just 4` and `return' (Just 4) = Just 4`.

One way to do so is

```
{-# LANGUAGE TypeFamilies, FlexibleInstances, OverlappingInstances #-}
import Control.Applicative
type family Maybed a where
  Maybed (Maybe a) = Maybe a
  Maybed a = Maybe a

class Returnable a where
   return' :: a -> Maybed a
```

You need a *closed type familie* in here because `Maybe a` matches bot rules. The closed type familes allows you to defines rules which overlap and use the first which matchest.

The `Maybe` instance is trivial

```
instance Returnable (Maybe a) where
  return' = id
```

The *normal* instance is a bit more tricky `instance Returnable a` would overlap with the previous one. For this, we need a way to say `a is not a Maybe`. Fortunatly, we can express the fact that `a` is not a `Maybe` if `Maybe a` is the same as `Maybed a`.

```
instance (Maybe a ~ Maybed a) =>  Returnable a where
  return' a = return a
```

Et voila !
You can write now a `lift'` function

```
lift' f a b = do
    a' <- return' a
    b' <- return' b
    f a' b'
```

And use the lifted function with every combination of `a` and `Maybe a`.

```
f a 0 = Nothing
f a b = Just (a `div` b)
f' :: ( Returnable a
      , Returnable b
      , Maybed a ~ Maybe a'
      , Maybed b ~ Maybe a'
      , Integral a')
      => a -> b -> Maybed a
f' = lift' f
```

The only problem is, because the type families can't infer types **backward** you'll have to specify the type for each paramters, so I'll use `x` and `y` for the examples.

```
x = 2 :: Int
y = 3 :: Int

> f' x y
Just 0
> f' x (f' x y)
Nothing
```